# How to call handlebars helper within other helper declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js, handlebarshelper

Is it possible to call already registered helper while declaring new one?

**Example**:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('td', function(text, options) {
    return "<td>" + text + "<td>";
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('tr', function(cells, options) {
    return "<tr>" + (cells.map(cell => {
        return td(cell); // it is where I want to call my other helper
    }).join("")) + "<tr>";
});
```

Example above is just *an example*, not my real case, which would overcomplicate presenting problem.
Only thing I found so far according to the matter of *helpers within* are [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions), but it doesn't seem to apply to my case.

I am using [hapijs](https://hapijs.com/) with vision, if that matters, however pure handlebars solution, if exists, is enough for me to recreate it in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should exclude td helper function and reuse it inside declaration of other helpers